# is missing in props validation react/prop-types

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, redux

- i am new to js.
- fixed other lint errors not able to fix only props lint errors
- i am getting a below lint error, googled for the error not able to figure whats the problem.
  17:20  error    'playerLaughing' is missing in props validation     react/prop-types
- provding the code below
- can you guys tell me how to fix it

```or-tag-here
C:\workspace\sports-dia-dashboard\src\components\sample-player\player-section.jsx
  17:20  error    'playerLaughing' is missing in props validation     react/prop-types
  17:40  error    'id' is missing in props validation           react/prop-types
  23:9   warning  Unexpected var, use let or const instead      no-var
  23:53  error    'jumping' is missing in props validation     react/prop-types
  28:32  warning  There should be no space before '='           react/jsx-equals-spacing
  28:32  warning  There should be no space after '='            react/jsx-equals-spacing
  30:37  error    'flying' is missing in props validation        react/prop-types
  33:21  warning  Empty components are self-closing             react/self-closing-comp
  44:3   error    Expected indentation of 4 spaces but found 2  indent



import React from 'react';


class Swimming extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.playerLaughing = this.playerLaughing.bind(this);
    }

    playerLaughing() {
          //console.log("playerLaughing");
         // debugger;
        this.props.playerLaughing(this.props.id);
    }

    render() {
          //console.log("render");
          //console.log("accordion / the ExpandCollapse Section component");
        var className = 'player-section' + (this.props.jumping ? ' jumping' : '');

        return (
            <div className={className} onClick={this.playerLaughing}>

                <div className = "sports-player-question-flying sports-submenu-dropmenuHeader">
                    <h3>
                        {this.props.flying}
                    </h3>

                    <div className="up-arrow"></div>
                </div>

                <div className="body">
                    {this.props.children}
                </div>


            </div>
        );

  }

}


export default Swimming;
```

Answer (score 10):

You need to set the static property 'propTypes' on the component to satisfy this lint error.

Here is some info about React's PropTypes: [React Docs](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/typechecking-with-proptypes.html)

You would add a section similar to this:

```
import React from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';

class Swimming extends React.Component {
 static propTypes = {
   jumping: PropTypes.bool,
   playerLaughing: PropTypes.func
 };
 constructor(props) {
 ...
}
```

You'll need to install the 'prop-types' npm package.

Comment: hey, I added the below line but I am getting this error Uncaught ReferenceError: PropTypes is not defined
can you tell me how to fix it

Uncaught ReferenceError: PropTypes is not defined
  render()
  {
         const {playerLaughing, jumping} = this.props;
     }
        SectionExpandCollapse.propTypes = {
      playerLaughing: PropTypes.func,
      jumping: PropTypes.bool
  };

Comment: You need to install and import the PropTypes package from npm. In your console type ```npm install -S prop-types``` then right under where you import react type ```import PropTypes from 'prop-types'```

Answer (score 7):

You should add `propTypes` to your component:
For example:

```
// this goes outside the class deceleration 
Swimming.propTypes = {
    playerLaughing: PropTypes.func,
    jumping: PropTypes.bool,
    //... other props you will use in this component
};
```

If you want it inside the `class` deceleration you can use a static class field like so:

```
// this goes inside the class deceleration
static propTypes = {
        playerLaughing: PropTypes.func,
        jumping: PropTypes.bool,
        //... other props you will use in this component
    };
};
```

You should install and import `PropTypes`.  see the [Docs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/prop-types)

```
npm install --save prop-types
import PropTypes from 'prop-types'; // ES6 
var PropTypes = require('prop-types'); // ES5 with npm
```

Comment: hey, I added the below line but I am getting this error Uncaught ReferenceError: PropTypes is not defined
can you tell me how to fix it

Uncaught ReferenceError: PropTypes is not defined
  render()
  {
         const {playerLaughing, jumping} = this.props;
     }
        SectionExpandCollapse.propTypes = {
      playerLaughing: PropTypes.func,
      jumping: PropTypes.bool
  };